# encodeObject: encodeInt: Doesn't the encoder already know the type?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Just started working with `NSCoder` + `NSKeyedArchiver` (and I'm a beginner with Objective C).

Wondering why we have to specify the data type when encoding (`encodeObject: encodeInt:` etc.)since the type has already been defined for all vars. Is data typing only a compiler time assistive thing to prevent type mismatches that might occur at runtime? Is it for speed, so that the encoder doesn't have to check the type?

Simple question but I'm wanting to know a bit more about what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, only primitives are listed.  You can't write primitives into a coder so there are convenience methods to turn them into actual objects before storing them (and vice versa).  For example, encodeInt will turn the int into an NSNumber object.  Otherwise you would have to do it yourself every time ;).

Comment: but since the int is declared as an int, why doesn't NSCoder, etc. just figure it out? - that is what I was wondering about. I know about the specific methods for primitive types.

Comment: because "int" is not an object, it is a primitive.  It can only be passed as an "int".